# Does a MKMapView have its own location Manager?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, location, mkmapview

There is a CLLocationManager i have created, and receiving the gps updates from that , but my doubt is whether the mapview has its own locationmanager, in that case there will be two location managers right? Whether this will affect my application? in case its having its own location manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MKMapView has its own location manager.That's why you can directly show user location on map like this `myMapView.showsUserLocation=YES;`

Why are you using separate location manager im MKMapView? You can capture current user location by this way.

```
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [[myMapView userLocation] location].coordinate;
        double currentLat = location.latitude;
        double currentLong = location.longitude;
```

Also I dont think using separate location manager in MKMapView cause any problems.

Comment: It doesn't. Up until the point you start writing automated tests for location-related code, figure out you can't control the default location manager enough for your tests, wrap it into the simulator and then suddenly notice that your map view doesn't care about this simulator at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. And it shouldn't effect your application as long as you choose one and stick with it. Although, I will point out that having two (or one empty) is terrible coding practice. Use the following function to access your `MKMapView`'s locationManager:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

Comment: But how to request first location access from the user with this location manager? Do I have to create one just for requesting location access?